# SpriteKit Scene Images showing as red cross on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm having a problem with loading in images onto a scene:

- I've added to my project Images/start-button.png (+@2x +@3x)
- I've created a new scene: MenuScene.sks
- I've added a Sprite object to the scene.
- I've selected from the drop down in the texture field "start-button"

On my scene display I can see my Start Game button.

But when I load the simulator I get:

```
SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "start-button"
```

[image: Xcode Preview]

Simulator Preview:

[image: Error Image]

These images are not oversized (about 300x150) and they load programatically in my scene using:

```
SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Images/start-button")
```

Does anyone know what I've done wrong here?
Many thanks!

Comment: You are using a folder structure, which is probably what is throwing off the simulator.  Is there any reason why you are not doing this in assets?

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop **start-button.png** into the *Assets.xcassets* area and try running the simulator again